# Seafarer transiting through Dubai

Tags: transit, indian-citizens, dubai, seamans-book

I am a seafarer signing off from ship in Turkey, and travelling to India through Dubai. Is it possible for me to stop over in Dubai for a few days? I am an Indian citizen holding an Indian seaman, book valid US C1D visa and a Schengen visa.

Answer (score 1):

Dubai offers a 96 hours transit visa for airlines and other companies for their crew to utilize.

Seamen can use the same visa for entering Dubai for the purposes of embarking / disembarking. However, this visa must be applied for in advance and from Dubai.

It is not a "visa on arrival" as you may be used to.

Unfortunately your other visas do not offer you any additional privileges as far as entering Dubai.